# Change the Border Style of a Focused Text Box using Blend and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, expression-blend

I've been headdesking over this for quite some time. Can someone please explain to me, using Expression Blend, how to edit/override the default FocusVisualStyle for a text box? Currently all of my text boxes have that blue accent when they're selected, and this doesn't match my current application's theme, but I just can't figure out how to override this. I think I've set the Border brush in about 10 different places in various templates, events, and properties, and it just won't override.

Edit: Buttons do this, as well, and it looks even more ugly. I'd like a solution that incorporates all controls that behave like this.

A set of directions for Blend would be preferable to just pasting XAML, but at this point I can't get picky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you're seeing is actually part of the ListBoxChrome element that exists within TextBox's default control template. You could easily swap this out with a simpler template that uses the BorderBrush property, which is what Silverlight's TextBox does.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Border x:Name="Bd" 
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
            CornerRadius="2">
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: What am I supposed to do with this XAML? Just insert it? I'm using Blend, so Blend-specific instructions would be helpful...

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with Blend. Even with a tool like Blend you need to have a solid understanding of control templates and styles in order to do something as involved as theming an application. The problem you're having is not something that can be solved with a simple property setting. You actually need to change the control template of the TextBox control to replace one of its parts.

Comment: But in any event, to make the above apply to all TextBoxes in your application you'd have to put it in the App.xaml resource dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer, for Blend, you can right-click the Control to define a new template. Once you do that, in the XAML view, replace the generated `<ControlTemplate>` with the one @Josh Einstein provided. I also added SnapToDevicePixels onto the border so it wouldn't anti-alias, but this is optional. After you do this, to change the Text Box's border or background color, use the Template. But to change the text's foreground color, use the object instance instead (not the template).